# cakephp isAuthorized() not working properly

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a very peculiar problem with `isAuthorized()`. Here is the function in `AppController`:

```
public function isAuthorized () {
    if ($this->Auth->user('role') == USR_ADMIN) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

so basically, administrators have access to everything. This works OK untill using the admin prefix routing. When accessing `UsersController::admin_view()` I get an "Unauthorized" message.

So first, I though that the function simply isn't returning true. So I tested it:

```
public function isAuthorized() {
    if ($this->Auth->user('role') == USR_ADMIN) {
        printf ("returns true"); exit;
        return true;
    }
}
```

So now I know that the function actually returns true, but I still get the "Unauthorized" error. What could be causing this?

Thank you.

Comment: you'll have to show the code using the isAuthorized function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the "problem".

```
public function isAuthorized () {
    if (in_array($this->action, $this->userAllowed)) {
        return true;
    }

    parent::isAuthorized ();
}
```

The parent::isAuthorized() was the problem because I wasn't returning it. A simple `return parent::isAuthorized()` fixed the problem.

Stupid, I know, but this thing had me puzzled for hours.

Comment: I can't access `User::USER_ADMIN` in `isAuthroized()` from `User` model even after including `$uses=array('User');`, is it a legal call or I have to import Model explicitly ?